# RSpec matcher for request rendering text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, rspec

Is it possible to examine if `get` request rendered text?

I know there are hacks like `response.body == 'any string'` but it does not interest me. I'm just wondering if there is "RSpec™" way to do it.

Having this rspec:

```
RSpec.describe MyController, type: :controller do
  controller do
    def index
      render text: 'Hellow'
    end
  end

  describe 'rendering' do
    subject { get :index }
    it { is_expected.to render_template(text: 'Hellow')}
  end
end
```

I would love to be able to call `it { is_expected.to render_template(text: 'Hellow')}`. It raises:

```
 Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to render_template(text: 'Hellow') }
 ArgumentError:
   Unknown key: :text. Valid keys are: :layout, :partial, :locals, :count, :file
```

or maybe `it { is_expected.to render_template('Hellow')}`

```
 Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to render_template('Hellow') }
   expecting <"Hellow"> but rendering with <[]>
```

Is there any RSpec™ way to accomplish it?

Comment: Try to add [`render_views`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-1/docs/controller-specs/render-views) because RSpec [does not render views](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-1/docs/controller-specs/do-not-render-views) by default

Comment: RSpec seems to use `response.body == 'Hellow'` in this [example](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/anonymous-controller#anonymous-controllers-only-create-resource-routes)

Comment: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1482 :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing `expect(response.body).to eq('Hellow')` is totally appropriate.

The reason `is_expected.to render_template` isn't working is you aren't rendering a template. If your controller omitted an explicit `render` call, Rails would render the `index` template for you, and you could test `render_template(:index)`. You could also `render template: :foo` and then test `render_template(:foo)` if you wanted to render a nonstandard template. But when you `render text: 'Hellow'`, you aren't using templates; you're explicitly setting the response body to the text you specify.

If you do render a template, and you want to test the content rendered by that template, that's when [`render_views`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-3/docs/controller-specs/render-views) comes into play, as [gotva mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33391579/rspec-matcher-for-request-rendering-text#comment54574988_33391579). Even then, you'd be checking for content in `response.body`, as you can see in RSpec's own examples. As your templates get complicated, the controller specs aren't the appropriate place for this and you should start writing [view specs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#testing-views) using `assert_select` or something similar.